# Xamarin Forms Designer in VS2019 other form factor

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I develop a Xamarin Forms application for a small android device (480x800 4"). The designer has several "devices", but not such a small one - is there a way to add an own device definition?
[image]

Comment: I didn't find a place where I could create a custom device. Maybe you could try creating a custom emulator to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The styling for multiple device resolutions could make it adaptive.

First, create new resource files small devices. Then create a method to detect the device size. After that set the resource file based on device size. Add styles to each resource file and spply the styles to your XAML. At last, we have styles that better fit the resolution of the devices we are targeting.

For more steps, you could refer to the link below. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/styling-for-multiple-device-resolutions/

You could download the source file from the GitHub for reference. https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultipleDeviceResolutionSample

Comment: I'm not talking about flexible resolution - I want a designer view that shows me (without deployment) how it will look on my device - ...is there a way to add an own device definition???